# Unable to cancel async task execution

Tags: java, android

Am getting exception when the user continuously clicking the button on which am calling the async task.
So is there any way to cancel the execution of first async task execution on second time pressing the button.
I hope u understand the problem.

The codes am using is given below.

On button click am using the following code

```
        GetData obj= new GetData();
        String urls="http://pathramonline.com/?cat=46";
        obj.execute(urls);
```

My async task

```
    public class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            BufferedReader reader =null;
            String data =null;

            try{

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                URI uri=new URI(params[0]);

                HttpGet get =new HttpGet(uri);

                HttpResponse response= client.execute(get);

                InputStream stream=response.getEntity().getContent();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

                StringBuffer buffer =new StringBuffer("");
                String line="";
                String newLine= System.getProperty("line.separator");

                while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                    buffer.append(line+newLine);
                }
                reader.close();
                data = buffer.toString();


                return data;

            }
            catch(URISyntaxException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(ClientProtocolException f){
                f.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(IOException g){
                g.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
            //
            }
            finally{
                if(reader!=null){
                    try{
                        reader.close();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){

                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
         @Override
            protected void onCancelled() {


            }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //TextView t3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            if(result==null)
            {
            Intent home = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NoConnection.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(home);
            MainActivity.this.finish();
            }

            //Some actions
        }
  }
```

Comment: Use progressbar or hide the button and make it visible in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: but is there another way to do it without the help of progressbar?

Comment: Hide that button :D and make it visible in onPostExecute().

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest another method instead of cancelling the asynctask.
In your onPreExecute() method disable the button click

```
button.setEnabled(false);
```

And in onPostExecute() method enable back the button

```
button.setEnabled(true);
```

If you explicitly want to know that button is disabled then while the asynctask is being executed you can change the background color of the button to another color or background, so that the user will know that some function is being carried out and he needs to wait..

Another approach is

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            String result = "";
            ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading , Please wait...");
                progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                progressDialog.show();
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String url = "your link comes here"



                JSONObject jsonObject = jpass.getJSONFromUrl(url);

                try {
                    //do your work here 

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void a) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                progressDialog.dismiss();

                if (result.equals("success")) {
                    //on success do some work here 
                }
                else
                {
                    //on failure do some work here 
                }
                super.onPostExecute(a);
            }

        }.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of cancelling the `AsyncTask` just set your button's click listener to null and then again set it inside `onPostExecute` of your `AsyncTask`. It would be even better if you display a `ProgressBar` when your `doInBackground()` code is executing.